# Choose the record that is next to the maximum number in kdb

Tags: kdb

need to find a way to choose the records that are next to the maximum numbers in the table for each sym group:

Eg:

```
numm:1 2 3 4 5 6 5.5 4 3 
tab:([]sym:`a`b`c;time:(20:00:01 + til 9; 21:00:01 + til 9;22:00:02 + til 9);num:(numm;numm + 10;numm+ 100))
ungroup tab

\\need to find the time where num = 5.5,15.5,105.5 which are always next records to the maximum number in the same sym group.
```

now I can get the max sym by each group:

```
select max num by sym from tab2
```

However, not sure how to get the record next to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach should handle the case where there are multiple records with the same max value:

```
q)select from tab2 where({prev til[count x]=last iasc x};num)fby sym
sym time     num
------------------
a   20:00:07 5.5
b   21:00:07 15.5
c   22:00:08 105.5
```

Comment: thanks! trying to understand the logic here. so loop through all num for each sym to get the last ascending num, and get the counts , but why do we use the prev on the count instead of next?

Comment: It's a boolean test (i.e. the one for which the index equals the index of the last in the ordered list) but you wanted the one for which the *previous* number satisfied that test (aka the one after)

Answer (score 2):

The below code will achieve what you want (assuming tab2: ungroup tab - which I believe is what you meant in your original post):

```
q)tab2 1 + exec i from tab2 where num=(max;num) fby sym
sym time     num
------------------
a   20:00:07 5.5
b   21:00:07 15.5
c   22:00:08 105.5
```

If you need any clarifications on what's happening ask away.

Comment: what if there is the same max number like 6 6 6 6 in the record? trying to select the last i for last maximum: tab2 1 + exec i from tab2 where num=(last max;num) fby sym

Answer (score 2):

if you're after the adjacent record **following** a maximum value the following will do the trick

```
q)select from tab where({0>deltas x=max x};num)fby sym
sym time     num
------------------
a   20:00:07 5.5
b   21:00:07 15.5
c   22:00:08 105.5
```